# local language variables to use in code for queries(NOT GLOBAL LANGUAGE)

Tags: i18n-l10n

I'm building a site in multiple languages (Italian and English) and I would like to ask you to intervene on the code to add selections 'if' to my queries to the user's local language.
At first I place conditions using as a reference global $ language but I understand that it is wrong as it does for the whole site and not a single user.
I saw on the internet that you can use sessions but how do they do? I would also switch to change languages. I have no idea how to do.
I went in configurations -> REGIONAL AND LANGUAGE -> languages -> detection and selection .. here that I have to give exactly?
How should I do help me please!

Answer (score 1):

If the user is logged in, you can the global `$user` variable. The language object is then `$user->language`. For an anonymous user, you can use a session variable or a cookie. There's a module to use cookies: [Language Cookie](https://www.drupal.org/project/language_cookie)

To use a session variable:
On the "Detection and Selection" configuration page, set "Session" as the first detection method. To set up the variable, click the "Configure" link on that page. You should see
[image: Session language detection configuration]

Then you just need links to set the user's language. Something like

`http://yoursite.com/?language=en` and `http://yoursite.com/it?language=it`
at the top of the page.